# R: fastest way to summarize by group?

Tags: r, performance, optimization, data.table

What is the absolute fastest way to summarize by group in `R`? I've used `data.table` to optimize this step as much as I can but it's still the main bottleneck in my code as it has to run thousands of times.

```
library(data.table)
data <- matrix(rnorm(5e6 * 16), ncol = 16)
colnames(data) <- paste0("mark", 1:16)
group <- gl(10, 5e5, labels = paste0("sample", 1:10)) 
DT <- data.table(group, data) # 1/10 actual row #
out <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {mean(x^3)}), by = group]
```

Comment: Hard to beat `data.table` - in R or any other language. [These benchmarks from H2O.AI](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/) show that `data.table` wins or is near the top depending on size of data  / number of groups for grouped sums compared to `dplyr` or several other language alternatives known for their performance. Can you set key on the data.table first? Especially if you're doing other grouped operations that should speed things up some.

Comment: No difference with `DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {mean(x^3)}), by = key(DT)]`. However, it's good to know that someone else came to the same conclusion

Comment: If you're really trying to wring some speed out of this, I just benchmarked `x*x*x` versus `x^3` with 1000 numbers, and the former worked about 5x faster. If you are summarizing fewer than 1000 numbers at a time, it is never slower than `x^3`, and starts to show even slight speed improvements with as few as 20+ numbers.

Comment: Use verbose to ensure GForce optimization is running. I am not sure if it won't be disabled by x^3 inside. Then compute that as new column and then call mean on a materialized column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As r2evans mentions, the `mean` function is not the slowest part. It is the power function `x^3` for all data.

We can see this if we separate the calls and measure time.

```
system.time(x <- lapply(seq_along(DT)[-1], function(i) DT[[i]]^3)) # 4.7
system.time(setDT(x)) # 0
system.time(x[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = DT$group]) # 0.41
```

In this specific case I can propose:

```
v2 <- function() {
  x <- lapply(seq_along(DT)[-1], function(i) DT[[i]]*DT[[i]]*DT[[i]])
  setDT(x)
  x[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = DT$group]
}
```

timing:

```
v1 <- function() {
  DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {mean(x^3)}), by = group]
}
system.time(v1()) # 4.92 
system.time(v2()) # 0.84
```

Also,

```
x[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = DT$group]
x[, lapply(.SD, function(i) mean(i)), by = DT$group]
```

are different. First one invokes `data.tables` `gmean`, but the second call doesn't. Depending on the size of your data one could be faster then the other approach.

Comment: You're right, `v2()` is about 2x faster using my actual dataset. Interestingly, v1 and v2 results differ by about 2.740863e-16. I'm guessing that has to do with `gmean`